# How do I switch between the header and implementation file in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode

How do I switch between the header and implementation file in Xcode 4?

In XCode 3 it was cmd and right or left (I think)

Comment: For those who have SizeUp app installed, its default keyboard shortcut for moving Space Above/Below might interfere when you try to execute Ctrl+Cmd+Up or Down keyboard shortcut. So dont forget to take those shortcuts out.

Comment: Not strictly answering the question but check out AppCode by JetBrains ( http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/). It's a vast improvement over XCode and switching between declaration and implementation is as easy as Command + b (with the added bonus of it actually doing it, unlike XCode).

Answer (score 202, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>, but the shortcut seems a bit finicky and sometimes stops working, not yet sure when and why.

---

## Be sure to FIRST click ON the actual code window...

that's the critical tip to ensure it works. Click anywhere at all on the actual code. (If you're active in one of the other many panes of Xcode, the keystroke combo has no, or different, meaning(s).)

Comment: Thank you, it was driving me nuts that I couldn't figure out the new shortcut in 4. I was so mad they changed it!

Comment: For a company that prides itself on usability and ease-of-use; how can Apple manage to make XCode so confusing to work with.  No, this is not a rant; it's an honest comment: does Apple not value the developers who work on Mac and iOS applications? Are we "less" than consumers?

Thank you for the question and the answer; my work is difficult enough without having to wrestle with XCode's shortcomings.

Comment: Yeah it takes a while to get used to but eventually one gets there!

Comment: stopped working for me as well for some reason, restarted xcode and it's working again.

Comment: One occasion when it stops working is when you rename a class using the refactoring tool.

Comment: @RobertAltman - not just that, Xcode is a piece of crap and Apple is apparently happy with Xcode's 2 to 3 star rating around the world. I hate it with passion.

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can 3 finger swipe up and down on the touchpad if you have one.

Comment: Not in Lion anymore... That's now Mission Control :-/

Comment: @Ame, This really made me upset. :(

Comment: If you hold option and 3 finger swipe down xcode will show the assistant editor which has both the header file and implementation file.

Answer (score 6):

Ctrl+Cmd+Up or Down

The shortcut sometimes stops working!!

The menu option has moved to "Navigate->Jump to Next Counterpart" and "Navigate->Jump to Previous Counterpart".

In preferences the key binding is now under "Jump to Next Counterpart" and "Jump to Previous Counterpart".

Why Apple insist on changing the menu positions AND names of these things is beyond me! I mean "Counterpart"!?

Worth nothing that Ctrl+Cmd+Left or Right move between previous and next files that were viewed (I mean "counterparts") too. These are also under the key bindings "Jump to Next Counterpart" & "Jump to Previous Counterpart").

Answer (score 4):

The reason the menu option has been split between:

"Navigate->Jump to Next Counterpart" and "Navigate->Jump to Previous Counterpart"

is because you can have more than just one header file and one source file with the same file name. Besides having matching .xib files for view controllers, I have separate .vsh and .fsh files for vertex and fragment shaders in my OpenGL program. Along with my .h and .cpp files that's a list of 4 files that I can navigate up or down through with one key binding, instead of hitting the same key binding 3 times in a row to cycle back from file 2 to file 1.

Answer (score 2):

Also in **Xcode 6.1/7.1** shortucts are the same:

Jump to next counterpart:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

Jum to previous counterpart:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

Personally, coming from eclipse, I change this shortcut with:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

this combination insn't already binded to anything else.

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Key Bindings
```

search for "Jump to next counterpart" and put the new keys combination.

## PRO

This is **more efficient** than default bindings see that you can use one hand instead of two!

Answer (score 1):

"but the shortcut seems a bit finicky and sometimes stops working, not yet sure when and why."

Sometimes Xcode loses track of which .m and .h belong together. This is e.g. the case
when you open one of the files directly from the Finder. When you open the file from 
the file list in Xcode, it normally works okay. Although when you have moved files between
folders & groups in the file list of Xcode, it will also list the relation between the files.

Comment: If I have 2 .mm/.h pairs open it does this for me.
For example if FileB.h is open, then from FileA.mm, it will switch to FileB.h instead of FileA.h
Any workarounds?

Answer (score -1):

The command to swap between m and h files is CTL-CMD-up/down. It sometimes get stuck. To unstick it simply save the file, i.e. CMD-S, and the hotkey should work again.