# xcode 4 switch between header and source

Tags: xcode4

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300947/how-do-i-switch-between-the-header-and-implementation-file-in-xcode-4)

indicates that it is ctrl+cmd+up or down just like xcode says but mine seems to be revealing in finder even though the shortcut says otherwise.
[image]

Anyone else having this issue? How do you fix it.

Comment: I should add that this was fixed (for me at least) in a later version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using key combinations I like to use gestures for most of these kinds of actions in Xcode. For this one simply slide 3 fingers up or down and wait a moment. It will switch between the header and implementation file. I find it works very well on a Macbook Pro trackpad or my Magic Trackpad which has the enough space for these gestures. If you have a Magic Mouse you may not have enough space for this and other gestures.

I think you will find it easier to remember this gesture over the key combinations.

Comment: It works great on the track pad but not so well when I hook up the magic mouse.