# Xcode shortcut for jumping to implementation of a method?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Xcode for jumping to the implementation of a method?  I am aware of the fact the command+click will jump to definition, but I want to jump to the implementation method, not the definition.  Also, I want to use keyboard shortcuts, with no involvement of the mouse (including clicks).

Comment: After you got to the method definition by command + click, do it again on the method signature to go to it's implementation.

Comment: No. When you *defined* the method in a header file Xcode will jump to this **DEFINITION**. There's a difference to *IMPLEMENTATION*.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300947/how-do-i-switch-between-the-header-and-implementation-file-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 17):

Keyboard shortcut for 'jump to definition' in XCode 4.5: Control-Command-J

Another useful shortcut after jumping to definition is Control-Command-Left (which takes you back).

Comment: Except that the question is to do with jumping to implementation as distinct from definition, and which this answer leaves us none the wiser for.

Comment: this answer is not relevant to the question

Comment: This is the way to toggle between definition and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Command + click will work, If you want "keyboard only" shortcut you need to map it under Preferences->key bindings->Edit->Find->jump to definition

Comment: This is "jump to definition", not "jump to implementation". It's exactly the opposite. This will take you to the header files if the method is *defined* there.

Comment: this answer is not relevant to the question

Answer (score -2):

Hold Command and click on the method you want to see it's implementation.

Comment: As of XCode 9, this still just jumps to the definition - you only see the implementation if the implementation is also the definition, i.e., you didn't define the signature in a header file.  I also would like to be able to go from the definition to the implementation, but I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: this answer is not relevant to the question