# Equivalent of Xcode "open-counterpart" feature in Visual Studio

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-2017

I was working on Xcode for C++ development earlier and it's code editor had an option where when a header file was opened it would automatically open the .cpp on the assistant editor.

I am talking about this feature:

"[How do I switch between the header and implementation file in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300947/how-do-i-switch-between-the-header-and-implementation-file-in-xcode-4)"

Now I have moved on to Visual Studio 2107. Though it is pretty intuitive in itself, I still miss this feature. Is there any feature similar to "open counterpart" in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension with AutoOpener add-in enabled to automatically open corresponding .h or .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks! This one seems good but I was looking for some inbuilt feature or a free add-in.